# How to fix the orientation of the page to Landscape in Application Craft?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, orientation, landscape

I have a adobe form which I need to incorporate in my mobile app which I created in application craft, But since the form is a little wide, opening it in Landscape solves my purpose. This is the reason I need the page to be fixed in Landscape while other pages will rotate according to the phone movement.

The only thing I have got is that there is a phone gap property but it sets the orientation of the complete app and not a page. So is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, set this for all your activities:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Let me explain:

- With `android:configChanges="orientation"` you tell Android that you will be responsible of the changes of orientation.
- `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` you set the default orientation mode.